# Dell 4600 Driver for Audio Card Windows 7

Tags: windows, audio, drivers

I just installed windows 7 on dell 4600 desktop.  the Audio card is a Creative Labs Sound Blaster Audigy 2.  I've look all over, and I can't find a driver for windows 7.  I've also looked at Vista Drivers.  It seems Dell is not supporting Windows 7 with this computer.  I've got a work around, but would like a driver if possible.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Creative Labs has OEM drivers for Windows 7 x32/x64. They should work without any problems.

[Audigy 2 Windows 7 Drivers](http://support.creative.com/Downloads/searchdownloads.aspx?filename=SBAX_PCDRV_LB_2_18_0011.exe)

Comment: +1 yep, that's the one, i needed this one last week myself for a Dimension 4600 :)